# How to pick furniture and carpeting that is safe for a home with low ventilation?

Tags: safety, furniture

To improve energy efficiency, many homes are now made to reduce and control the amount of fresh air that is circulated from outside.

However, I'm told that many cushions used in couches and materials used in flooring such as carpeting emits dangerous gases over time and that in a home that is tightly sealed, these gases can reach unsafe levels.

Therefore, when shopping for furniture or flooring materials such as carpeting, how can I know the level of these issues in products I am considering?

Comment: Just opening a window once a week to circulate some air can be quite efficient. Personally I would not like to live in a house with bad circulation of fresh air.

Comment: I quess old furniture should have emitted most of the poisonous gasses already. Also you could use non mass produced furniture that you can be sure that it's safe.

Comment: @jkj just because something isn't mass produced doesn't mean it doesn't contain any harmful chemicals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For carpeting and carpet cushions, you can look for products that meet the requirements of the Carpet and Rug Institute's [Green Label Plus program](http://www.carpet-rug.org/commercial-customers/green-building-and-the-environment/green-label-plus/).